# How can I generate a map of list of strings

Tags: terraform

I need a map of list of strings for this module:

```
module "my_bindings" {
  source   = "terraform-google-modules/iam/google//modules/projects_iam"
  projects = ["myproject"]
  mode     = "additive"
  bindings = <MAP OF LIST OF STRINGS>
}
```

I'm trying to generate this from a nested loop like this:

```
# can pass in a list of roles
variable "my_list_of_roles" {
  type        = set(string)
  default = [
    "roles/role1",
    "roles/role2",
    "roles/role3",
  ]
}

# can pass in a list of GSAs
resource "google_service_account" "service_accounts" {
  for_each     = tomap({ for i in var.mygsas : i.account_id => i })
  account_id   = each.value.account_id
  display_name = each.value.account_id
  project      = "some_project"
}

# For each GSA generate apply the list of roles to a specific project
# This is the wrong format
locals {
  proj_bindings = [
    for i in var.my_list_of_roles : {"${i}" = [for s in google_service_account.service_accounts : s.member]}
  ]
}

module "my_bindings" {
  source   = "terraform-google-modules/iam/google//modules/projects_iam"
  projects = ["myproject"]
  mode     = "additive"
  bindings = local.proj_bindings
}

# view the var I'm generating
output "test" {
   value = local.proj_bindings
}
```

The format I'm generating looks like this which I wrong, how do I build a *map* not a list?

```
  + test = [
      + {
          + "roles/role1" = [
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        },
      + {
          + "roles/role2" = [
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        },
      etc
```

## Edit

This is the format I need to generate:

```
my_var = {
  "roles/role1" = [
    "sdfsdfsdfsd",
    "sdfsdfsdfdsdfsdfs",
  ]
  "roles/role2" = [
    "sdfsdfsdfsd",
    "sdfsdfsdfdsdfsdfs",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the loop in your locals to match the format the module requires, like this :

```
locals {
  mock_service_accounts = [
    { member : "serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" },
    { member : "group:my-group@my-org.com" },
    { member : "user:my-user@my-org.com" }
  ]

  my_list_of_roles = [
    "roles/compute.networkAdmin",
    "roles/appengine.appAdmin",
  ]

  proj_bindings = {
    for role in local.my_list_of_roles : role => [
      for s in local.mock_service_accounts :
      s.member
    ]
  }
}

# + proj_bindings           = {
#     + "roles/appengine.appAdmin"   = [
#         + "serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
#         + "group:my-group@my-org.com",
#         + "user:my-user@my-org.com",
#       ]
#     + "roles/compute.networkAdmin" = [
#         + "serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
#         + "group:my-group@my-org.com",
#         + "user:my-user@my-org.com",
#       ]
#   }
```

With that you will have a value pretty much the same as the module example from https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/iam/google/latest/submodules/projects_iam

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change your locals to this:

```
locals {
  proj_bindings = {
    for i in var.my_list_of_roles : i => {"${i}" = [for s in google_service_account.service_accounts : s.member]}
  }
}
```

However, you need a key expression, therefore your output would look like this:

```
proj_bindings = {
      + "roles/role1" = {
          + "roles/role1" = [
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        }
      + "roles/role2" = {
          + "roles/role2" = [
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        }
      + "roles/role3" = {
          + "roles/role3" = [
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
              + (known after apply),
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is also the wrong format. They aren't nested like that. I will add to my question.